# wordpress query for pages with arrays not working

Tags: php, templates, wordpress-theming, wordpress

Hi I am trying to get a couple of pages out of wordpress by using a query.

when I do

```
$query= new WP_Query('page_id=5880');
```

everything is fine

However,

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'page', 'page_id' => array( 5880, 5840 ) ) );
```

produces nothing. What am I missing please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `page_id`, it should be `post__in`:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'page', 'post__in' => array( 5880, 5840 ) ) );
```

See https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters

Comment: thanks - that works. Suppose I was a bit taken in by page_id thinking that if you set post_type to page then since page_id says 'use page id' it would give you those pages. Obviously not!